# git checkout .(dot) interactive

Tags: git

I know `git checkout .` is one of the most dangerous commands in the git universe (rightfully so). Is there a way to make it interactive? Like how the `rm` command works with `-i` option.

I am looking for something along the lines of

```
git checkout . -i
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git checkout` (and `git add` as well) support the `-p` option, which will ask you for every hunk, like this:

```
diff --git a/post.so b/post.so
index b111bdd..ddba6b1 100644
--- a/post.so
+++ b/post.so
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
-`git checkout` (and `git add` as well) support the `-p` option.
+`git checkout` (and `git add` as well) support the `-p` option, which will ask you for every hunk, like this:
+
+foo bar
Discard this hunk from worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
```

For every hunk you can answer:

```
y - discard this hunk from worktree
n - do not discard this hunk from worktree
q - quit; do not discard this hunk or any of the remaining ones
a - discard this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not discard this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```